# Problems with facebook share, how does login method influence share behavior?

Tags: facebook, ios6

I have an ios 6 app with a facebook login on the first page. I am using facebook-sdk 3.2.
The login process is similar to the [scrumptious tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/).
So if there is a session, the user is logged in automatically, else he has to press login.
I have also a share dialog. It is similar to the [share tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-native-dialogs-ios-sdk/).

1. If a user has filled in his facebook login in the **iOS-Settings**,
   there is a native login dialog (the popup box). If the user logs in
   and touches the share button there is the **native share dialog**.
2. If a user has **not** filled in his facebook login in the **iOS-Settings**, there is a fast-app-switch-login. If the user logs in and touches the share button he ends up in the **fallback share dialog**.

Now to the odd part:

If a user goes way 2, closes and restarts the app, he gets logged in automatically if the facebook session exists. If the user then touches share, the **native share dialog** (expected the fallback share dialog) pops up and the user is asked to fill in his credentials in the iOS-Settings.

Is there a way to get the behavior consistant? I don't care if there is the fallback share dialog or the native dialog with the request.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that facebook works on a single sign-on experience. When user goes the #2, it also logs the user into facebook.

Comment: As this put me in the right direction, but didn't gave me a concrete solution, I only vote this answer up, but don't checkmark it